# InAppBrowser IOS 14

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, redirect, inappbrowser, ios14

The issue is simple, we have an error using the inappbrowser in iOS 14 where once you open a new browser with inappborwser component, if the web flow changes to another domain different than the first one, the connection between the browser and the app is dropped. This only happens with iOS 14.

I'm using angular, ionic and Cordova.

Anyone have the same problem? Anything that can we do with the app to fix it? How can I contact Apple to report this issue?

Comment: I'm currently facing exact issue, have you solved ?